# Flutter: CheckboxListTile select with checkbox only?

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, checkbox

In Flutter, using the CheckboxListTile, is there a way to disable selecting an item when clicking on the label text and only allow it to be selected when clicking on the checkbox itself? My list moves the selected items down to the bottom of the list and marks them as "completed." With a long list it can be difficult to realize which item you accidentally pushed when scrolling. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, one way to get around this is to use a separate checkBox widget and create the labeling yourself.

Comment: You can use a ListTile and add a checkbox to the leading attribute.

Comment: Thank you, both. I ended up disabling the onChange and requiring a double-click to complete the item via GestureDetector. I was already using the widget for LongPress to edit, so it Works well.